# how to fit gaussian smooth curve in dtg plot in R

Tags: r, plot, gaussian, smoothing

i have created plot using R, but can not add smooth curve

```
par(mar=c(5, 12, 4, 4) + 2)
plot(data2$Program_Temperature, data2$Unsubtracted_Weight, type = 'l', col = 2,
 xlab = 'Program_Temperature', ylab = 'Unsubtracted_Weight')
par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$Program_Temperature, data2$Unsubtracted_Heat_Flow, type = 'l', col = 3,
 axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", lty = 2)
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(range(data2$Unsubtracted_Heat_Flow)))
mtext("Unsubtracted_Heat_Flow", side = 4, line = 2)

par(new = TRUE)
plot(data$Program_Temperature, data2$new, type = 'l', col = 4,
 axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", lty = 3)
axis(side = 2, at = pretty(range(sort(data2$new))), line = 5)      
mtext("DTG", side = 2, line = 7)
```

[image: click to see the plot]

Comment: You seem to be missing some parentheses at the end of your code.

Comment: Yeah but in rstudio code is correct

Comment: Stackoverflow is a depository of knowledge, the next person that searches for this problem might not recognize something is missing. You know the code is wrong compared to your RStudio version, would you be so kind to edit your question so the code is correct?